How to remote connect HIVE DB
I am trying to connect from Server A to Server B (HIVE), tried JDBC and end up with error
JDBC Hive2 Kerbros Invalid status 21 error
While checking, found beeline can be used for connecting to HIVE. But i dont see any documentation for how to install beeline, what i found is this https://askubuntu.com/a/919525
Is this the correct way of accessing beeline, copying all needed jars and use it in the command?
Finally found all the required jars and here is what it is now
java -Xmx1024m -classpath cron-utils-9.1.6.jar:jackson-databind-2.10.5.1.jar:jackson-dataformat-yaml-2.10.5.jar:jackson-jaxrs-base-2.10.5.jar:jackson-jaxrs-json-provider-2.10.5.jar:jackson-module-jaxb-annotations-2.10.5.jar:re2j-1.2.jar:disruptor-3.3.7.jar:netty-all-4.1.68.Final.jar:javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar:log4j-1.2.17-cloudera6.jar:accessors-smart-2.4.7.jar:json-smart-2.4.7.jar:super-csv-2.2.0.jar:ant-launcher-1.10.12.jar:ant-1.10.12.jar:arrow-format-0.8.0.7.1.8.5-1.jar:arrow-memory-0.8.0.7.1.8.5-1.jar:arrow-vector-0.8.0.7.1.8.5-1.jar:avro-1.8.2.7.1.8.5-1.jar:curator-client-4.3.0.7.1.8.5-1.jar:curator-framework-4.3.0.7.1.8.5-1.jar:curator-recipes-4.3.0.7.1.8.5-1.jar:hadoop-annotations-3.1.1.7.1.8.5-1.jar:hadoop-auth-3.1.1.7.1.8.5-1.jar:hadoop-common-3.1.1.7.1.8.5-1.jar:hadoop-hdfs-client-3.1.1.7.1.8.5-1.jar:hadoop-hdfs-3.1.1.7.1.8.5-1.jar:hadoop-yarn-api-3.1.1.7.1.8.5-1.jar:hadoop-yarn-client-3.1.1.7.1.8.5-1.jar:hadoop-yarn-common-3.1.1.7.1.8.5-1.jar:hadoop-yarn-registry-3.1.1.7.1.8.5-1.jar:hadoop-yarn-server-applicationhistoryservice-3.1.1.7.1.8.5-1.jar:hadoop-yarn-server-common-3.1.1.7.1.8.5-1.jar:hadoop-yarn-server-resourcemanager-3.1.1.7.1.8.5-1.jar:hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy-3.1.1.7.1.8.5-1.jar:hive-beeline-3.1.3000.7.1.8.5-1.jar:hive-classification-3.1.3000.7.1.8.5-1.jar:hive-common-3.1.3000.7.1.8.5-1.jar:hive-jdbc-3.1.3000.7.1.8.5-1.jar:hive-llap-client-3.1.3000.7.1.8.5-1.jar:hive-llap-common-3.1.3000.7.1.8.5-1.jar:hive-llap-common-3.1.3000.7.1.8.5-1-tests.jar:hive-llap-tez-3.1.3000.7.1.8.5-1.jar:hive-metastore-3.1.3000.7.1.8.5-1.jar:hive-serde-3.1.3000.7.1.8.5-1.jar:hive-service-rpc-3.1.3000.7.1.8.5-1.jar:hive-service-3.1.3000.7.1.8.5-1.jar:hive-shims-3.1.3000.7.1.8.5-1.jar:hive-standalone-metastore-3.1.3000.7.1.8.5-1.jar:hive-storage-api-3.1.3000.7.1.8.5-1.jar:hive-shims-0.23-3.1.3000.7.1.8.5-1.jar:hive-shims-common-3.1.3000.7.1.8.5-1.jar:hive-shims-scheduler-3.1.3000.7.1.8.5-1.jar:orc-core-1.5.1.7.1.8.5-1.jar:orc-shims-1.5.1.7.1.8.5-1.jar:parquet-hadoop-bundle-1.10.99.7.1.8.5-1.jar:tez-api-0.9.1.7.1.8.5-1.jar:libthrift-0.16.0.jar:zookeeper-jute-3.5.5.7.1.8.5-1.jar:zookeeper-3.5.5.7.1.8.5-1.jar:bcpkix-jdk15on-1.68.jar:bcprov-jdk15on-1.68.jar:jettison-1.3.4.jar:apache-jsp-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:apache-jstl-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:jetty-annotations-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:jetty-client-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:jetty-http-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:jetty-io-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:jetty-jaas-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:jetty-jndi-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:jetty-plus-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:jetty-rewrite-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:jetty-runner-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:jetty-security-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:jetty-server-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:jetty-servlet-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:jetty-util-ajax-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:jetty-util-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:jetty-webapp-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:jetty-xml-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:websocket-api-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:websocket-client-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:websocket-common-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:websocket-server-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:websocket-servlet-9.4.43.v20210629.jar:javax.el-3.0.0.jar:javassist-3.27.0-GA.jar:objenesis-1.0.jar:asm-analysis-9.1.jar:asm-commons-9.1.jar:asm-tree-9.1.jar:asm-9.1.jar:snakeyaml-1.26.jar:jline-2.12.jar:commons-cli-1.2.jar:commons-io-2.16.0.jar:slf4j-api-2.0.12.jar:hive-exec-3.1.3.jar:woodstox-core-6.5.1.jar:stax2-api-4.2.1.jar:commons-collections-3.2.2.jar -Dhadoop.log.dir=/export/home/logs -Dhadoop.log.file=hadoop.log -Dhadoop.root.logger=INFO,console org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine
    SLF4J(W): No SLF4J providers were found.
    SLF4J(W): Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
    SLF4J(W): See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
    Beeline version 3.1.3000.7.1.8.5-1 by Apache Hive

beeline> !connect jdbc:hive2://bigdataplatform-gfts-uat.net:10000/otrc_icaps_staging;principal=caps_hive_uat/bdgtr05.net@CTIP.NET;ssl=true

But getting below error and not much details of why it is not able to connect, also i am missing kerbros setup, where should i mention that

Connecting to
jdbc:hive2://bigdataplatform-gfts-uat.net:10000/otrc_caps_staging;principal=caps_hive_uat/bdgtr05.net@CTIP.NET;ssl=true
org/apache/http/client/HttpClient 0:
jdbc:hive2://bigdataplatform-gfts-uat.net (closed)>


Yes almost.To use Beeline for connecting to Hive without installing the entire Hadoop or Hive ecosystem, you can opt for a minimal setup using only the necessary JAR files.

Identify Required JARs: On a system with an existing Hive installation, use the -verbose:class JVM option while running Beeline to log all classes loaded and their corresponding JAR files.
Copy JAR Files: Copy the identified JAR files from the existing Hive installation to a directory on your client machine (Server A).
Run Beeline: Execute Beeline using the Java command with all the necessary JARs included in the classpath. Example command:

java -Xmx1024m -classpath <path-to-jar-files-separated-by-colon> org.apache.hive.beeline.BeeLine


Thanks, Finally i am able to connect, but getting error like (closed) , update the question
